# When I use the parenthesis it says cannot be used as a method or delegate

Tags: c#

main.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Cust_Constructor
{
    class MyProg
    {
        static void Wr_L(object o)=>Console.WriteLine(o);//Includes a new line char
        
        static void Wr_i(object m)=>Console.Write(m);//Includes a new line char
        
        static void Main(){
            MyProg firstProg = new MyProg();//Creating an object
            firstProg.printing();
        }
        
        public void printing()
        {
            Student myself = new Student("Omar", "Belkady");
            myself.overrideThisPlease();
        }     
    }
}
```

User.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Cust_Constructor
{
    public abstract class User
    {
        static void Wr_L(object o)=>Console.WriteLine(o);//Includes a new line char
        
        static void Wr_i(object m)=>Console.Write(m);//Includes a new line char
        
        public User()
        {
            Wr_L("You know what I get printed out first because Student inherits from me!");
        }
        
        public bool User_Is_Verified{get;set;}=false;
        
        
        public static string FName{get;set;}
        
        public static string LName {get;set;}
    
        public abstract void overrideThisPlease();
    }
}
```

Student.cs

```
using System;

namespace Cust_Constructor
{
    //If you want to prevent people from creating Users directly
    //By forcing them to make a Student, Teacher, employee. You make the class abstract
    //If it is done then you will get an error: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class
    public class Student : User //Student Inherits From User
    {
        
        
        static void Wr_L(object o)=>Console.WriteLine(o);//Includes a new line char
        
        static void Wr_i(object m)=>Console.Write(m);//Includes a new line char 
        
        //Inherit and Override
        public override void overrideThisPlease()
        {
            Wr_L("Howdy Howdy y'all I just overrode the User meth and by I, I am the Student: "+Student.TheFullName);
            // If you place () The member `Cust_Constructor.Student.TheFullName' cannot be used as method or delegate
            
        }
        public static string TheFullName{
            get{
                return FName+" "+LName;
            }
        }
        
        //Creating the custom constructor for Student
        public Student(string FN, string LN)
        {
            FN = FName;
            LN = LName;
        }
       
    }
}
```

THE PROBLEM IS WITHIN STUDENT.CS FOR SURE. PLEASE HELP. I appreciate it.
If I place () to indicate I want to call the student method version I get the error:

> The member `Cust_Constructor.Student.TheFullName' cannot be used as method or delegate

If I do not then the program runs but no student Full Name is outputted.
Please help. I really appreciate you helping me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why `FName`, `LName` and `TheFullName` are static?

Comment: TheFullName is **not a method** - so do not call it as method. it's a property with a getter. there do not belong parentheses behind. you do not have a problem, you're using the property as it is meant to be used.

Comment: I used the new keyword to access the static methods within my class. But it is still giving me an error. I just want to print Omar Belkady by calling the method in my Student class

Comment: You need to learn what static means. All of your users have the same name (or rather the User class has a single name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong assignment order in `Student` constructor:

```
public Student(string FN, string LN)
{
    FN = FName;
    LN = LName;
}
```

Should be changed to this:

```
public Student(string FN, string LN)
{
    FName = FN;
    LName = LN;
}
```

Also you should make `FName` and `LName` (and `TheFullName`) instance properties (by removing `static`). Static means that property (in this case) is shared among all instances of class, so every new created student will override FName and LName: